# Exception in thread Main Error java.lang.numberformat.exception

Tags: ioexception

I am beginner to java.Can you tell me what is the problem here.It is compiling but I a unable execute.

```
import java.io.*;

class rect
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int length,width,area;
length=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
width=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
area=length*width;
System.out.println("area"+area);

}


}
```

Error:Exception in thread Main Error java.lang.numberformat.exception :5 10

Comment: The problem is the number format..... Check what you're trying to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input is not a number which cannot be parsed.

5 10 has a space in between.

Answer (score 0):

The program is fine, but you seem to be using it in the wrong way. Judging from the exception, you entered `5 10` on the console for the values of `length` and `width`, but both of those variables try to parse an entire *line* of input. That is, the input line `10 5` is read and  `length=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());` tries to parse this line as *one* integer number, which fails.

Instead, you should enter the two numbers separately: `10`, `<enter>`, `5`, `<enter>`; then it works.

Alternatively, you can enter both numbers in one line and then use `String.split` to split the line in two strings, both of which can then be parsed as integers.

```
String[] numbers = br.readLine().split(" ");
length = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
width  = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
```